# Read REG_MULTI_SZ type registry key in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, registry

I am able to read registry values using qt with types like `REG_SC` and `REG_DWORD` by doing

```
QSettings settings(registryPath, QSettings::NativeFormat);
settings.beginGroup(mDeviceName); // Filter out this device only
QStringList regReturn = settings.allKeys();

keyValue = settings.value(regReturn[i]).toString();
```

But when trying to read something of `REG_MULTI_SC` type I get nothing back. How can I read e.g the HardwareID key of an enumerated HID device where the HardwareID contains

```
HID\VID_1915&PID_0024&REV_0001&MI_00
HID\VID_1915&PID_0024&MI_00
HID_DEVICE_SYSTEM_KEYBOARD
HID_DEVICE_UP:0001_U:0006
HID_DEVICE
```

?

Comment: Try to use .toStringList() instead of .toString(). Or watch in debugger real type of value

Comment: What "nothing"? What data type is in QVariant?

Comment: @DmitrySazonov Sorry, I am not to experienced with Qt. The `keyValue` gets nothing in return from the `settings.value` expression. Could you explain more about what you mean with QVariant? I couldn't understand what you meant by only reading the docs

Comment: Ah, I got it know. It contains a QStringList so that is what I have to do when this happens, instead of just "toString()"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From @DmitrySazonov's comments I was able to do a debug on

```
v = QVariant(settings.value(regReturn[i]));
```

and find that `v` contained a `QStringList`. The solution was to do `keyValue = settings.value(regReturn[i]).toStringList();`

instead of `keyValue = settings.value(regReturn[i]).toString();`

Comment: Yepp! Should have posted that as an answer. I failed to do it correctly the first time around ;) I think I read the comment on my mobile and actually missed the first part of the sentence :P